# How to code NullPointerException safe method and expressions?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

`NullPointerException` is always a code clutterer. Need to check if every object is null safe and don't throw NPE.

I came across a situation:

```
 public void aMethod(Employee emp){
     String fullEmployeeDetailRow = "Name: "+emp.getName().getFirstName()
     +"LastName :"+emp.getName().getFirstName()
    +"Address:"
  +emp.getAddress().getBillingAddress().getBuildingNumber().getApartmentNumber()
  +" "    
  +emp.getAddress().getBillingAddress().getStreetName()
  }
```

In above example there are so many possibilities of NPE. For instance  in

```
emp.getAddress().getBillingAddress().getBuildingNumber().getApartmentNumber()
```

expression, call to

```
getAddress() or getBillingAddress() or getBuildingNumber()
```

any can be null and probable NPE source. So I now need to clutter my code to check if each can be null.

My Question / Thought is: is there a way in Java to CREATE a method which takes  an expression and evaluate if it throws `NullPointerException` and if yes then return a default value, say a blank `" "`?

So in this case I need a method

`expression=emp.getAddress().getBillingAddress().getBuildingNumber().getApartmentNumber()`

```
String checkForNPE(expression){
    try{
      return expression;
      }catch(NullPointerException e){
         return " "   // default Value
      }
    }
```

Problem is when I try to create a method like this , and pass an expression to it, Java evaluates the expression BEFORE calling the method and NPE is thrown beforehand!

How can I pass the expression to the method and ask Java  to evaluate it inside method only?

Comment: why don't you make the try block there where you initialize the expression ?

Comment: @Dimi  That's what I am trying to avoid. I am trying to avoid to check expression in my main code to avoid Null check / NPE  code clutter and looking to move that try/catch check to a separate  checkForNPE() method. As there can me many such expressions around same place ( See my example) and just delegate that check up code to a checkForNPE() and reuse for all expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Optional in this situation.

```
Option.ofNullable(emp)
      .map(e -> e.getAddress())
      .map(a -> a.getBillingAddress())
      .map(a -> a.getBuildingNumber())
      .map(n -> n.getApartmentNumber())
      .orElse("not set")
```

Comment: Thanks. Will explore this Java 8 feature.   Is there any similar solution in pre-Java 8 ?

Comment: Based on your answer , this article presents my question properly and your answer too.      http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Comment: @supernova There might be libraries which support this however without lambdas this code would be far more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

> NullPointerException is always a code cluttrer.

I disagree.

> Need to check if every object is null safe and don't throw NPE

That's not necessarily true.  It is often the case that allowing an NPE to be thrown from your method is the most reasonable thing you can do in the event that some reference it tries to use is unexpectedly `null`.  Certainly the standard library takes that approach in many places.  The most likely reason to "need" to verify that every reference is non-`null` is an artificial standard imposed from outside.

> My Question / Thought is , is there a way in Java to CREATE a method which takes an expression and evaluate if it throw NullPointerException and if yes then return a default value say blank " " .

I hesitate to say that it's impossible, but certainly there is no *easy* way to write a general-purpose method such as you describe.  Java makes no provision for evaluating Java source code at runtime.  Besides, what would be the point?  Instead of invoking such a method, you can just execute the code inside a `try` block; if it throws an NPE then catch it, and handle the situation however is appropriate.  There is no need to pre-test the expression.

> How can I pass the expression to the method and ask Java to evaluate it inside method only?

You cannot.  Or at least, Java makes no provision for it, as I already said.  Whatever expression you use as a method argument is evaluated before the method is invoked, and a copy of the result is passed to the method.  Again, use a `try` / `catch` directly -- pretty much anything else you could consider doing is far more complicated and more costly.

Alternatively, there are approaches such as @PeterLawrey's that make it easier and prettier to test every single reference.  That's not what you asked, but perhaps it suits you.